Zero scheme of gloabl sections on projective variety
Let $K$ be a field, $A:=K[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ be a finitely generated $K-$algebra, where $I$ is a homogeneous ideal. Let $X:=\text{Proj}\;A$ with canonical closed immersion $i:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_K$.
My question is: how to show, for any global section $s\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_K,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_K}(d))=K[x_0,...,x_n]_d$, the zero subscheme (for a definition, see for example 02OQ) of global section $i^*s\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(d))$, denote it as $Z(i^*s)$, is exactly the image of the canonical closed immersion $\text{Proj}\;A/(\overline{s})\rightarrow X$.
Motivation: This question is natural when people study the zero scheme of global section in projective space. When $X=\mathbb{P}^n_K$, the question is asked in MSE.

How to ask a good question. Some problems present: (a) spelling mistakes, (b) non-functioning link, (c) no motivation, (d) no context, (d) no own progress.

@MartinBrandenburg. Thanks for point out. I fix the typo and add some relative links of this question. Any comment would be appreciated.

The same proof linked in the MSE question works nearly verbatim here. Have you tried to adapt it to your case?
